# Выводит в консоль что имя "tfds" не определенно

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, tensorflow

Все библиотеки установлены, не понимаю в чём проблема. Помогите пожалуйста!
[image: Все библиотеки установлены, не понимаю в чём проблема. Помогите пожалуйста!]
python у меня 3.11.4

Comment: Не добавляйте отчеты об ошибках в виде картинок.

Comment: И приведите код полностью. Так очень сложно что-то понять.

Comment: Похоже, вообще. на то, что библиотека tensorflow_datasets все-таки не установлена. Других вариантов просто нет.

Comment: А вы первую ячейку то выполнили прежде чем вторую запускать?

Comment: @Глеб Ну нет, тогда ошибка была бы другая

Comment: @CrazyElf, вы правы. Тогда была бы ошибка "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_datasets'". Но почему же тогда возникает ошибка, если модуль импортирован правильно?

Comment: @Глеб Это интерактивный питон и файл формата `jupyter notebook`. Я подозреваю, что автор вопроса просто не выполнил первую ячейку с импортами, а запустил сразу вторую ячейку. Да, такое тоже бывает.

Comment: @CrazyElf СПАСИБО (ну я и тупой), всё заработало!!!